# Allow only numbers to be typed in a textbox - default to zero

Tags: javascript

How can this be modified so that if a user does not enter a number the number 0 will be entered into the text field, thank you in advance:

```
    function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: If the enduser types "42ab7", shall it be "0" or "42007"?

Comment: The text field is set to 0 by default. What I want to happen is that if the user clears the default 0 and then fails to enter a number then the default 0 will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a user does not enter a number then 0 will be entered into the text field

```
<input type="text" id="numeric" value="0" onclick="this.value='' " onblur="if(this.value==''){ this.value='0'} "  />
```

regex for numbers only.

```
$('#numeric').on('input', function (event) { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/WsznL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use IsNumeric and check if 0 too.

```
IsNumeric(number goes here)
```